# Open ERP Ace Editor widget

Tags: odoo, ace-editor

I added new widget which allow edit text in perfect Ace Editor.
[Github](https://github.com/Shpionus/ace_editor)

Maybe someone will need such widget.
Also I would like to receive some feedback. What need to add or what work not correctly?

Answer (score 1):

The best way would be to advertise your module at the [OpenERP Community](https://launchpad.net/~openerp-community) mailing list.

Another suggestion is to add it to the [Web Addons](https://launchpad.net/web-addons)  community reviewed project, by making a [merge proposal](https://doc.openerp.com/contribute/15_guidelines/contribution_guidelines/#merge-proposals-patches).

You can find more information [here](http://odoo-community-association.org/02_projects.html).

Comment: By the way, I [tweeted](https://twitter.com/reis_pt/status/475598007652851712) about it and it seems to have generated some interest.